# How to turn off "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs"?

Tags: javascript, popup, alert

How to turn off "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" when i use window.unbeforeunload?

Comment: Why do you think this exists in the first place?

Comment: first place? what do you mean?

Comment: step 1) write your own browser, step 2) ???, step 3) **profit**

Comment: step 1) my browser is chrome.... :D

Comment: What everyone is trying to say is, you *can't*. That is a browser specific implementation that you cannot "turn off".

Comment: Furthermore, that alert only appears when a certain page is sending an unusual amount of alert boxes - why would you ever want to remove that option?

Comment: because i want the user of the application always see the alert if they wanna close tab and if checkbox with "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" message is checked by the user so that alert not appear again. : (

Comment: Please post your code